# final part of a QUERY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am finishing a query that I have been asked but I can not finish it, the structure of the tables is as follows:

**child**

```
CREATE TABLE CHILD(
child_id SMALLINT,
child_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(255),
city VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT PK_CHILD PRIMARY KEY(child_id)
```

**Sibling**

```
CREATE TABLE SIBLING(
child_id1 SMALLINT,
child_id2 SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_SIBLING PRIMARY KEY(child_id1, child_id2),
CONSTRAINT CHILD1_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id1) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id),
CONSTRAINT CHILD2_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id2) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id)
);
```

**letter**

```
CREATE TABLE LETTER(
letter_id SMALLINT,
arrival_date DATE NOT NULL,
number_toys INTEGER NOT NULL,
delivery_mode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
child_id SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_LETTER PRIMARY KEY(letter_id),
CONSTRAINT CHILD_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id)
);
```

**wished_toy**

```
 CREATE TABLE WISHED_TOY(
 letter_id SMALLINT,
 toy_id SMALLINT,
 CONSTRAINT PK_WISHED_TOY PRIMARY KEY(letter_id, toy_id),
 CONSTRAINT LETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY (letter_id) REFERENCES LETTER(letter_id)
 CONSTRAINT LETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY (toy_id) REFERENCES TOY(toy_id)
 );
```

**toy**

```
CREATE TABLE TOY(
toy_id SMALLINT,
toy_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL NOT NULL,
toy_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
manufacturer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_TOY PRIMARY KEY(toy_id),
);
```

They ask me to make a query that contains the list of children that have asked for a toy also requested by one of their brothers (Sibling). Specifically, the identifier of the child is required child_id, the name child_name and their date of birth birth_date .

I have this part of the query already, but something fails me, I do not know how to compare the toys that each child has requested ...

```
SELECT ch.child_id,ch.child_name,ch.birth_date,wi.toy_id
FROM child ch 
right outer join sibling si ON ch.child_id= SI.child_id1
left outer join letter l 
on ch.child_id=l.child_id
left outer join wished_toy wt on l.letter_id=wt.letter_id
```

This query returns me the toys that each child that has brother and his brother asked for.
My question is how to get the list of repeated toys, I mean the two brothers have asked.
Couples of brothers are
child_id (1,11) (6,10) (3,12) (8,13)

**RESULT OF THE QUERY**

```
1,    'Daniel'   ,'2005-05-01'   ,7
1,    'Daniel'   ,'2005-05-01'   ,5
1,    'Daniel'   ,'2005-05-01'   ,9
1,    'Daniel'   ,'2005-05-01'   ,4
1,    'Daniel'   ,'2005-05-01'   ,3
1,    'Daniel'   ,'2005-05-01'   ,1
11,   'Mireia'   ,'2009-06-10'   ,9
11,   'Mireia'   ,'2009-06-10'   ,7
11,   'Mireia'   ,'2009-06-10'   ,5
11,   'Mireia'   ,'2009-06-10'   ,4
11,   'Mireia'   ,'2009-06-10'   ,8
 6,    'Elena'   ,'2001-02-18'    ,5
10,   'Guillermo','2003-12-21'   ,1
10,   'Guillermo','2003-12-21'   ,4
10,   'Guillermo','2003-12-21'   ,9
 3,    'Raquel'  ,'2002-03-08'    ,5
 3,    'Raquel'  ,'2002-03-08'    ,2
12,   'Sergi'   ,'2012-08-29'   ,12
12,   'Sergi'   ,'2012-08-29'    ,7
12,   'Sergi'   ,'2012-08-29'    ,2
12,   'Sergi'   ,'2012-08-29'    ,5
8,    'Pedro'   ,'2008-03-30'    ,3
8,    'Pedro'   ,'2008-03-30'    ,4
8,    'Pedro'   ,'2008-03-30'    ,8
13,   'Sara'    ,'2002-08-29',  NULL
```

For example it is seen that brothers 1 and 11 have ordered the same toy, toy 9 and 7.
How can I get only the two of them for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    insert into child values (1, 'child1', '1-1-2010', 'male', null, null);
    insert into child values (2, 'child2', '1-1-2010', 'male', null, null);
    insert into child values (3, 'child3', '1-1-2010', 'male', null, null);

    insert into sibling values (1, 2);

    insert into letter values (1, '1-1-2010', 2, 'asdf', 1);
    insert into letter values (2, '1-1-2010', 2, 'asdf', 2);
    insert into letter values (3, '1-1-2010', 2, 'asdf', 3);
    insert into letter values (4, '1-1-2010', 2, 'asdf', 1);


    insert into toy values(1, 'toy1', 1, '', '');
    insert into toy values(2, 'toy2', 1, '', '');
    insert into toy values(3, 'toy3', 1, '', '');

    insert into wished_toy values(1, 1);
    insert into wished_toy values(2, 1);
    insert into wished_toy values(3, 2);
    insert into wished_toy values(4, 1);

    select distinct c1.child_id, c2.child_id
from sibling s, child c1, child c2, letter let1, letter let2, wished_toy w1, wished_toy w2
where
  (c1.child_id = s.child_id2 and c2.child_id = s.child_id1
   or c1.child_id = s.child_id1 and c2.child_id = s.child_id2)
  and w1.letter_id = let1.letter_id
  and let1.child_id = c1.child_id
  and w2.letter_id = let2.letter_id
  and let2.child_id = c2.child_id
  and w1.toy_id = w2.toy_id
  and c1.child_id < c2.child_id
```

distinct is necessary to prevent duplicated results when there are multiple letters from a single child. the id

Comment: My problem is: If child 1 asks for play 2 in a letter and child 2 asks for toy 2 in another letter.
How do the ones, I mean, how do I relate them? I'm going to edit to put the result of a test that can clarify things more

Comment: my query takes this into account if I understand you right

Comment: the query returns pairs of siblings that requested the same toy in their letters

Comment: if you have 3 siblings that request a same toy, you will get 3 pairs as result

Comment: I apologize for not having explained well the problem I had, I think now with the editing it looks good what I @MarianP

Comment: try the query in my answer

Comment: Perfect, with this I have two pairs of children who ask for identical toys but ¿how do I get their names and date of birth? With this I have their id but not their name or date of birth, I do not know how to get it out. @MarianP

Comment: just add c1.child_name, c1.birth_date, c2.child_name, c2.birth_date to the select